# multiple criteria to subset sample - R

Tags: r, subset

Dear Stackoverflowers R users,

I am trying to subset my sample based on 3 critera. I try to write down a sample of the dataframe:

```
Name       Name2       Gender Thus_o
Mariana    Valentina   woman      
Valentina  Valentina   woman  Mela
Valentina  Valentina   woman
Mariana    Valentina   man
Valentina  Valentina   man
Valentina  Valentina          Mela
```

The following three are my subsetting criteria.

```
#1
dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, Name == Name2) # keep if name is the same as name2

#2
dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, Name != "Mariana " &
                          Gender!= "man" |
                          Name != "Valentina " &
                          Gender != "man")  # keep all of the observations except those for whom the name differs from Mariana and the gender is reported to differ from man or those for whom the name differs from Valentina and the gender is reported to differ from man (i.e. drop if there is female name but the reported gender is man)

#3
dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, Gender== "" & Thus_o!="")  # drop if Gender is empty and Thus_o is not empty (I do not know if it matters but notices that Gender is not "NA", it is empty and it has to be so for a specific reason)
```

The first subsetting criterion works well (I run piecewise the script), but criterion 2 does not seem to work well and, after I run criterion 3 as well, my data frame becomes empty!

*What Am I doing wrong and how can it get the expected result?*

My subsetting should return me one observation:

```
Name       Name2       Gender Thus_o
Valentina  Valentina   woman  Mela
```

*NOTE:*
I tried to decompose criterion 2 as follows but the results is the same:

```
#2.a
dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, Name != "Mariana " &
                          Gender!= "man")
#2.b
dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, 
                          Name != "Valentina " &
                          Gender != "man")
```

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible by including `dput(dataframe1)` and show expected output ?

Comment: I am new to R, what is dput()?

Comment: It is way to share your data so that we have can work on the same data as you. Type `dput(dataframe1)` in your R console and copy and paste the output in your post. Also include what output you would expected for the data shared.

Comment: Sorry, for now I have to give up on dput(). The dataset is huge and I can see only a fraction of the dateset. Maybe I can try to write down a little piece.

Comment: `dput(head(dataframe1))` will do, we don't need the whole thing. Would `test <- expand.grid(Name=c("Mariana","Valentina"),Gender=c("man","woman"))` be representative?

Comment: I think you can simplify your logic potentially. Just write it as you would say it - `subset(dataframe1, !(Name %in% c("Valentina","Mariana") & Gender == "man") )`  subset to cases that are not `!` where there is a female name, and the gender is man.

Comment: Your #3 selection has `Gender== ""` - this is never the case in your example data so you get nothing returned.

Comment: @thelatemail Gender=="" actually is present in the complete dataset; by mistake I did not report this case, now it is there

Comment: You are treating everything as strings. But it might be that some columns are formatted as factors (a very common problem in R). You can test this by `str(dataframe1)` and look whether every column is a character as type or whether there is one factor under them. Or just convert all columns to characters `for(i in 1:ncol(dataframe1)){dataframe1[, i] <- as.character(dataframe1[, 1])}` and then try your subsetting again.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim - i don't think that complication is necessary to understand here, particularly as `"" == factor("")` and `"a" == factor("a")` both return `TRUE`

Comment: Really? I had in past problems with factor columns ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I hve just found out that actually all of the variables are factors. Might that be a problem, since each Name and Name2 is followed by a blank space.

Comment: @Fuca26 if you read-in tables, add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your arguments list (most table reading functions offer it). It is bad that R has `TRUE` as default. Only helpful for statistics people but often even for their usage not. And highly unintuitive behavior because normal human brain thinks in strings. If I forgot this argument, I often ran into problems.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim - I suppose you can get strange circumstances like `factor("a",levels=c("a","b")) == factor("a",levels=c("a","b","c"))` but I was trying to avoid complicating the discussion if errors weren't being thrown already.

Comment: @thelatemail No, it was definitely not such a complicated case. Factors don't behave like strings simply. It is a language design mistake of R to try to treat as many columns as possible as Factors.

Comment: @thelatemail okay it might be okay as long as one only do comparisons. Things begin to get awry if one begins to use string expecting functions on factors ...

Comment: Maybe the second criterion has to be `!(Name != "Mariana" & Gender != "man") | !(Name != "Valentina" & Gender != "man")` ? "Keep except differ" ... there are so many negation of negations ... how to positively formulate the conditions?

Comment: I have done the following ```dataframe1<- subset(dataframe1, !(Name == "Mariana " & Gender == "man"))```

Comment: I do not know if it matter, but I have also turned the data frame into string:  ```str(dataframe1)``` and then
```dataframe1[] <- lapply(dataframe1, as.character)```